# Clicking a link using nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

What I have is:

```
 <a href="/test-guinea-pig2.html" id="i am a link">i am a link</a>
```

How would I go about clicking that using nightwatch.js? click() isn't working out.

Answer (score 0):

You click the same way you would do with a CSS selector:

`browser.click('#my-id')`. That said the id in your example is invalid ([link to what is a valid id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)) so you better rewrite it like `i-am-a-link` or something better.

Answer (score 0):

if we use 
    browser.click('#my-id')
it will look in the entire dom to identify the element.

The better and faster way to do will be

```
.click('a[id="i-am-a-link"]')
```

by filtering using 'a' only the anchor tags in the dom will be searched for .